# Getting the generated key for a multi-column primary key in JDBC

Tags: sql-server, jdbc

I want to get the generated key from an insert.

My code:

```
stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
ResultSet generatedKeys = stmt.getGeneratedKeys();
int columnCount = generatedKeys.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
if (generatedKeys.next()) {
    do {
        for (int i=1; i<=columnCount; i++) {
            String key = generatedKeys.getString(i);
            System.out.println("KEY " + generatedKeys.getMetaData().getColumnName(i) + " = " + key);
         }
     } while(generatedKeys.next());
}
```

This works fine.

My question is now: When I have a table with a multiple primary key, the value is always null. Why is this so?

Comment: When you say "multiple primary key" do you mean "multi-column primary key"? Is that primary key automatically assigned? If so, how?

Comment: HI, yes, I mean multi column primary key. The values are not automatically designed.

Comment: Okay, so if the primary key values are not *automatically* assigned then they must be provided as parameters to the INSERT statement, and therefore you already know what those values are. So why do you think you need to retrieve them after the INSERT takes place?

Comment: In my application I don't know the structure of the database, the user can enter the data as xml and I insert it into the database. So when the primary key is no autoincrement value, I will get null in this case, am I right?

Comment: Yes, I believe that you are right: There is no key value being *generated* so `getGeneratedKeys()` has nothing to return. It sounds like perhaps you might want to determine the *column(s)* that form the primary key for a given table so you know which column value(s) become the key value. In any case you should [edit] your question to better explain what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Hi, with your last comment i know everything I need to know at this point. I get the primary columns from meta data and solve this on my own

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getGeneratedKeys()` method is intended to return the key values that are automatically generated by the database when inserting into a table with a single "Identity" column (a.k.a. "AutoIncrement", "AutoNumber", and probably key values generated by a Sequence as well).

Depending on the implementation details of the JDBC driver, it *might* be possible to retrieve other automatically-generated primary key values, e.g., if a multi-column primary key value was assigned by an INSERT trigger or some other mechanism. However, that is not particuarly likely and certainly not something that you could count on.

And of course, if the primary key value is *not* automatically generated (as in your case) then it should come as no surprise that `getGeneratedKeys()` does not return anything because there is nothing to return.